# jQuery DOM - Inserting multiple nodes in li (menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, nodes

I know there are dozens of similar topics but I am so dumb I can't learn anything from it.
Other words: My code is just mean and doesn't work with any fixes published online. ;)

My HTML:

```
<ul id="main_menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

and how the LI should look after JS does its magic:

```
...
<a href="#" class="roll-link"><span data-title="Link 1">Link 1</span></a>
...
```

JS/JQ mission:

- add class="roll-link" to every A
- add SPAN right after A tag
- add data-title="xxx" attribute to SPAN with A value (text exactly the same as the A)
- close SPAN tag before A closing tag

My JS try:

```
var menuLis = document.querySelectorAll("ul.main_menu li"); //It's an Array right?

for(var i=0; i<menuLis.length; i++) {
   this.nextChild.setAttribute('class', 'rollink');
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   this.nextChild.nextSibling.insertBefore(span); //Auto-closing </span> may be an issue... 
   span.setAttribute('data-title', hrefvalue[i]); //but how to get value?
}
```

It may be total crap but I have completely no experience in JS/JQ, only had few hours of basic training online...

Thanks for reading and even bigger thanks for trying to help.

Greets!

Answer (score 1):

it should be as simple using jQuery(because you tagged it with jQuery)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#main_menu li a').addClass('roll-link').wrapInner(function () {
        return $('<span />', {
            'data-title': $.trim($(this).html())
        });
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q6yET/)

See

- [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)
- [dom ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

---

To make your code work, first the `main_menu` is an id, not a class so you need to use id selector, then try

```
var as = document.querySelectorAll("#main_menu li a");

for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    as[i].className = 'rollink';
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('data-title', as[i].innerHTML);
    span.appendChild(as[i].firstChild);
    as[i].appendChild(span)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y72zH/)

Comment: Whenever I am typing my answer, someone springs with an answer. +1 for annoying me ;)

Comment: This is wrong as it will always put `data-title="Link 1"` for every links.

Comment: @plalx yes just fixed that

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main_menu > li > a').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).addClass('roll-link').contents().first();
    text.wrap($('<span>').attr('data-title', text.text()));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Bw723/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution with pure Javascript.

```
//get the li elements
var menuLis = document.getElementById("main_menu").getElementsByTagName('li'); 
for(var i=0; i<menuLis.length; i++) {
   menuLis[i].firstChild.setAttribute('class', 'rollink');
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.setAttribute('data-title',  menuLis[i].innerHTML);
   //If you want to get href of a then use this one.
   //span.setAttribute('data-title',  menuLis[i].href); 
   //appending the span into a        
   menuLis[i].firstChild.appendChild(span);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8tUTQ/)